# How to call function on every value of String List and change it?

Tags: c#, string, foreach

I have a List of Strings and I want to check if they correspond to a specific form. If not i wan't to change that. But I didn't find a nice way to iterate over the elements of the List and change them.
I tried to go over `list.ForEach(tag => tag = foo(tag))` but that didn't change anything and with a `foreach (tag in tags)` loop it also (of course) didn't work.

Here is my code broke down to the problem:
(This code works but I would like it shorter at the comment in the Main Method)

```
class Sheet
{
  public string Name;
  public List<string> tags;

  public Sheet()
  {
    tags = new List<string>();
  }
}

class TagCleaner
{  
  public static string foo(string tag)
  {
    tag = tag.Replace("_", " ");
    return tag;
  }
}

static void Main()
{
  Sheet s = new Sheet();
  s.tags.Add("this is Valid");
  s.tags.Add("this_isn't");
  // is that somehow possible nicer?
  for (int i = 0; i < s.tags.Count; i++)
  {
    s.tags[i] = TagCleaner.foo(s.tags[i]);
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of foreach try with Select, ForEach iterate over all the list but is a void, it doesn't return any result. But with select you can do a projection  to return processed values.

```
s.Tags = s.Tags.Select(t => TagCleaner.foo(t)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using Linq to change your collection, it is not designed to do that. So your two options are either replace the collection as per Marc's answer or use a classic loop.